# How can I make a border to a matrix in java?

Tags: java, matrix

I have this matrix :

So 2 line and 2 columns.

- 1 2
- 3 4

I have the reading function

```
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            try {//    System.out.println("number is ");
                a[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();

            } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }         //print the input matrix
```

How can I make a border to a matrix? I've seen that in java there is no index -1.

I want a border with a number. For example :
 0  0  0 0

- 0 0 0 0
- 0 1 2 0
- 0 3 4 0
- 0 0 0 0

How should I make that border function?

Comment: It should probably be `int j = 0;` and not `1` in your for-loop. If you first explain out loud what a border is in English, then translating that to code will be easier, probably. When creating a border, you increase the width and height of the matrix by 2 respectively, so instead of a 2x2 matrix you now have 4x4, and the indices of the elements are incremented by 1.

Comment: Hint: initialize the array like this: `a[m+2][n+2]`. You should figure out the rest

Comment: I i it but I want that border

Comment: I can't figure out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create the matrix with extra rows and columns, for example in your case a 4x4 matrix. and them put 0 on the borders

when i==0 or i==n-1, j==0 or j==n-1,

```
int a[][] = new int[4][4];
int n,m;
n=4;
m=4;
for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
 for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
  if(i==0 || j==0 || i==m-1 || j==n-1){
   //a[i][j] = 0; 
   a[i][j] = 1;
   }
   System.out.print(a[i][j]+" ");
 }
  System.out.println();
}
```

then

```
for (int i = 1; i < m-1; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < n-1; j++) {
                    try {//    System.out.println("number is ");
                        a[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();

                    } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
                        // e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }         //print the input matrix
```

Answer (score 3):

So, you need a `(m+2) x (n+2)` matrix:

```
// initialize m and n
...
// initialize the matrix with 0s
int a[][] = new int[m+2][n+2];
```

Then ignore the first elements (`i` and `j` should skip `0`) and the last elements (`i` should skip `m+1`, `j` should skip `n+1`):

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
                try {
                    a[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
                } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my comment:

If you first put in words what creating a border means, then translating it from English to Java is a simple task.

Let's take a look at the the two matrices that you have given:

Original one:

```
1 2
3 4
```

With border:

```
0 0 0 0
0 1 2 0
0 3 4 0
0 0 0 0
```

We see that when creating a border, we increase the width and height of the matrix by 2 respectively (to have an empty row of `0`s on the top-bottom, and left-right), so instead of a 2x2 matrix we now have 4x4, and the indices of the elements are incremented by 1 (every element is pushed one step to the right, and one step downwards).

Putting this is in code:

```
int[][] createBorder(int[][] matrix) {
    //this is our 4x4 matrix
    int[][] borderedMatrix = new int[matrix.length+2][matrix[0].length+2];

    //fill the 4x4 matrix with 0's
    for(int i = 0; i < borderedMatrix.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < borderedMatrix[0].length; j++) {
            borderedMatrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    //copy the values of the 2x2 into the 4x4 matrix, but push them one step to the right, and one step downwards
    for(int k = 0; k < matrix.length; k++) {
        for(int l = 0; l < matrix[0].length; l++) {
            borderedMatrix[k+1][l+1] = matrix[k][k];
        }
    }
    return borderedMatrix;
}
```

Comment: you don't need to fill matrix with zeros because newly created matrix already filled by default values (0 for byte, short, int;  0.0 for float, double; false for boolean and null for reference types)

Comment: by the way, very good and intuitive solution, much simpler then others

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to create a matrix of `n+1xm+1`, populate the border with `0` then fill in the remainder with the original `nxm` matrix.

So if I had your example matrix

```
int[][] original = {{1, 2},
                    {3, 4}};
int borderWidth  = original[0].length + 2;
int borderHeight = original.length + 2;
int borderArray = new int[borderHeight][borderWidth];

for (int i = 0; i < borderWidth; i++) {   //border
    borderArray[0][i] = 0;                //populate top row
    borderArray[borderHeight - 1][i] = 0; //populate bottom row
    if (i == 0 || i == borderWidth - 1) { //populate left and right columns
        for (j = 1; j < borderHeight - 1; j++) {
            borderArray[j][i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) { //populate middle with original
    System.arraycopy(original[i], 0, borderArray[i+1], 1, original[].length);
}
```